# How to get link and title using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
html=
"""<div class="slick-list"><div class="slick-track" style="width: 1380px; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div data-index="0" class="slick-slide slick-active slick-current" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" style="outline: none; width: 230px;"><div><div data-courseid="567828" class="course-discovery-unit--card-margin--2TVw4 merchandising-course-card--card--2UfMa"><a href="/course/complete-python-bootcamp/" data-purpose="merchandising-course-card-body-567828" target="_self" class="merchandising-course-card--mask--2-b-d"><div class="merchandising-course-card--card-header--89z8L"><img class="merchandising-course-card--course-image--3G7Kh" alt="" width="240" height="135" src="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/567828_67d0.jpg" srcset="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/567828_67d0.jpg 1x, https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/567828_67d0.jpg 2x"></div><div class="merchandising-course-card--card-body--3OpAH"><div><div class="merchandising-course-card--course-title--2Ob4m" data-purpose="course-card-title">Complete Python Bootcamp: Go from zero to hero in Python 3</div>"""
```

I want to extract link and title output:

```
title=Complete Python Bootcamp: Go from zero to hero in Python 3
link=/course/complete-python-bootcamp/
```

Here is my code:

```
data=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"slick-list"})
print(data)

for link in data:
    for a in link.findAll("a"):
        print(a.title,a.href)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<div class="slick-list"><div class="slick-track" style="width: 1380px; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div data-index="0" class="slick-slide slick-active slick-current" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" style="outline: none; width: 230px;"><div><div data-courseid="567828" class="course-discovery-unit--card-margin--2TVw4 merchandising-course-card--card--2UfMa"><a href="/course/complete-python-bootcamp/" data-purpose="merchandising-course-card-body-567828" target="_self" class="merchandising-course-card--mask--2-b-d"><div class="merchandising-course-card--card-header--89z8L"><img class="merchandising-course-card--course-image--3G7Kh" alt="" width="240" height="135" src="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/567828_67d0.jpg" srcset="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/567828_67d0.jpg 1x, https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/567828_67d0.jpg 2x"></div><div class="merchandising-course-card--card-body--3OpAH"><div><div class="merchandising-course-card--course-title--2Ob4m" data-purpose="course-card-title">Complete Python Bootcamp: Go from zero to hero in Python 3</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print('title='+soup.find("div",{"data-purpose":"course-card-title"}).text)
print('link='+soup.find("a").get('href'))
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for this. it's still not working. 

actually i want to get the course name , instructor name and course fees from this website.. 

"https://www.udemy.com/courses/development"

here is few my code line. please help me if you can

""
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.udemy.com/courses/development"

results=requests.get(url)

src=results.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")

data_list=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"slick-list"})""

Comment: Try to find unique xpath for all the elements that you need and build that xpath in the soup find for the above example the title has a unique property called data-purpose with course-card-title so I used it for finding the title same wise find the unique xpath

Comment: If you find the ans is helpful kindly upvote so that id someone is searching for same kind of issue they can find it quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

I working solution based on your code (and using `findAll`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html= """<div class="slick-list"><div class="slick-track" style="width: 1380px; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div data-index="0" class="slick-slide slick-active slick-current" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" style="outline: none; width: 230px;"><div><div data-courseid="567828" class="course-discovery-unit--card-margin--2TVw4 merchandising-course-card--card--2UfMa"><a href="/course/complete-python-bootcamp/" data-purpose="merchandising-course-card-body-567828" target="_self" class="merchandising-course-card--mask--2-b-d"><div class="merchandising-course-card--card-header--89z8L"><img class="merchandising-course-card--course-image--3G7Kh" alt="" width="240" height="135" src="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/567828_67d0.jpg" srcset="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/567828_67d0.jpg 1x, https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/567828_67d0.jpg 2x"></div><div class="merchandising-course-card--card-body--3OpAH"><div><div class="merchandising-course-card--course-title--2Ob4m" data-purpose="course-card-title">Complete Python Bootcamp: Go from zero to hero in Python 3</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

data=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"slick-list"})
#print(data)

for div in data:
    for a in div.findAll("a"):
        print(div.text,a.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I wanted to get the course name, instructor name, and course fees from this website.. 

Website--"https://www.udemy.com/courses/development" 

here is few my code line. please help me ------ "" import requests import pandas as pd from bs4 import BeautifulSoup url="udemy.com/courses/development" results=requests.get(url) src=results.content soup=BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml") data_list=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"slick-list"})""